# My current code isn't working on this in python

Tags: python

[image: Python question]

This is my current code:

```py
n = int(input())
lst = []
for i in range(0, n):
    lst.append(input())
    if n == 'y':
        break
  

lst.sort()

print(lst)

k =len(lst)//2

if k==0 :
    print(lst[k+1])

else :
    print(lst[k])
```

this is the output it's giving me:

```
['3', '3', '6', '7']
6
```

and I need the output to be: `[3, 3, 4, 6, 7] 4`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the quit before adding it to the list. You also try to check for the number of integers you are given at the beginning - this is not what you want. The numbers given are terminated by the `q`.

```py
lst = []
while True:
    number = input()
    if number == 'q':
        break
    lst.append(int(number))
```

---

The slicing at the end is also incorrect. Let's break this down. You say

```py
k = len(lst) // 2

if k == 0:
    print(lst[k+1])
else:
    print(lst[k])
```

If we have `3, 3, 6, 7`, the length is `4`, so `k = 2`. Then, `k != 0` so we print out the element at index `2`, which is `6`. However, if `k = 0`, which is the case when the list has 1 element, you want to be accessing index `0`, not `1`.

---

This code

```py
lst = []
while True:
    number = input()
    if number == 'q':
        break
    lst.append(int(number))

lst.sort()

k = len(lst) // 2

print(lst)
print(lst[k])
```

now gives the correct output:

```
4
3
6
7
3   
q
[3, 3, 4, 6, 7]
4
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code that should give you the result you'd like to have.
See the comments for explanation

```
n = 50 #to limit the maximum number of inputs
lst = []
for i in range(0, n):
    x = input()
    if x == 'y':
        break
    lst.append(x) # this line should be after the break to avoid 'y' in your list
    
lst.sort()

print(lst)

k =len(lst)//2

if k==0 :
    print(lst[k+1])

else :
    print(lst[k])
```